# Avoid setRequestedOrientation delay

Tags: java, android, kotlin, android-intent, android-orientation

I'm experiencing a small undesired effect when trying to set the orientation of my activity:

I hace two activities: MainActivity and Activity2.

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
        findViewById(R.id.button).setOnClickListener(v -> startActivity(new Intent(this, Activity2.class)));
    }
}

public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        setRequestedOrientation(ActivityInfo.SCREEN_ORIENTATION_LANDSCAPE);
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main2);
    }
}
```

When I click the button with the device in portrait (but displaying the MainActivity in landscape) it loads the Activity2 in portrait and takes like 1 second to rotate to landscape.

How can I avoid this and load the Activity2 with the correct orientation from the start?

Note: This is a simplified example. It is not possible to set up the orientation in the manifest since the orientation is not fixed and depends on the user input.

Comment: The whole Activity should be destroyed and recreated from scratch, so the delay cannot be lowered more.

Comment: It is a rare behaviour, if the MainActivity does not request orientation the second activity is directly load in landscape without delay.

Comment: @Addev Has Activity2 always the same orientation with MainActivity? If this is the case you can use  android:screenOrientation="locked" to Activity2 manifest which locks the orientation to its current rotation (which is the same with MainActivity).

Answer (score 1):

Found a way to avoid the visual effect, but it is not elegant.

By declaring

```
public class Activity2 extends AppCompatActivity {
   ...
}
public class Activity2Land extends Activity2 {
   ...
}
```

And in the manifest

```
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2"
        android:screenOrientation="portrait"
        android:exported="false" />
    <activity
        android:name=".Activity2Land"
        android:screenOrientation="landscape"
        android:exported="false" />
```

you can workaround this issue. But, yes, you need to declare A LOT of activities if you want to support reverse and sensor orientations.

Any ideas for solving this in a correct way?